# Null pointer Exception at the end of draw processing3

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing

I get a Null Pointer Exception, and the trace tells me it is inside a function that I have. This function runs every frame and does some calculations and stuff. Anyway, the problem is that when I go to debug, stepping through each line, the function runs fine, and the error only comes up at the end of the draw loop.

This error only recently came up, and the changes I made don't have much to do with the function in question so...

The function mentioned in the trace detects if the object touches something, and acts on it.
Also, the trace gives a line number that does not exist, I'm guessing that's because of the Processing compiling.

I am using Processing 4 if that matters.

Here's the trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ants$Ant.sense(ants.java:190)
at ants$Ant.go(ants.java:220)
at ants.draw(ants.java:44)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2201)
at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$10.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1422)
at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:354)
```

Thanks!

Edit:
More info: This is an ant simulator, and it crashes at food pickup. This used to work and broke while adding (seemingly) unrelated stuff. It crashes at food pickup, which is managed by the `sense()` function. The Food class only has a position and a render function.
Here is some code:

```java
       void sense() { // The problematic function
        if (!detectFood && !carryFood) {
          float closest = viewRadius;
          Food selected = null;
          for (Food fd : foods){
            float foodDist = position.dist(fd.position);
              if(foodDist <= viewRadius) {
                  if(foodDist < closest) {
                  selected = fd;
                  closest = foodDist;
                }
            }
          }  
           if (selected != null){
             detectFood = true;
             foodFocused = selected;
           }
        } else {
          if(position.dist(foodFocused.position) < 2*r) {
            takeFood();
            detectFood = false;
          }
        }
      }
```

```java
void draw() { // draw loop
  background(51);
  for (Food food : foods) {
    food.render();
  }
  for (Ant ant : ants) {
    ant.go();
  }
  for (int i=0; i < trails.size(); i++) {
    Trail trail = trails.get(i);
    if (trail.strenght <= 0)
      trails.remove(trail);
    else
      trail.go();
  }
  }
```

The problem is not the trail, as it still crashes without it,

Comment: Can you post a minimal code example? It's unlikely anyone will be able to help based on what you've provided.

Comment: @cadin Added some more info

Comment: in `sense()`, in the `else` condition this line `if(position.dist(foodFocused.position) < 2*r) {` assumes `foodFocused` **always** has a value (`!= null`). Is that the case ? Might be worth adding a check beforehand. Other than that, the assumption is `foodFocused.position` and `this.position` are both `PVector` instances (also `!= null`).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza your first theory proved correct :D Thanks a lot.